# Joining two tables based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables 1 table with just id column, second table with id and source column. 
I am trying to create a match between table 1 & 2 based on ID and if source is equal to 1. I want to return status that id as a 'match', if source is 0, I want that id status to be 'not match'.

```
DECLARE @T1 AS TABLE (
    id int 

)
DECLARE @T2 AS TABLE (
    id int, 
    source int
)
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4),
(5)

INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES
(1, '0'),
(2, '1'),
(3, '0'),
(4, '1'),
(5, '1')
```

I am pretty much sure that It is a left join and join based on id from both the tables. But I am not sure how to create a new column and manipulate the 'match', 'no match' based on source condition

```
select id, status
from t1
left join t2 
on t1.id = t2.id
where 
case source = 1 'Match'
case source = 0 'Not Matched'
```

My expected results

```
id status
1  no match
2  match
3  no match
4  match
5  match
```

Comment: Why do you put `CASE` in `WHERE` clause?  Also have you read the documentation how to use `CASE`?  That's probably the first thing you should do before posting a question here.  That is not even a valid `CASE`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below, you should use case-when expression in your "select" line.

```
select t.id, [status] = case when t2.source = 1 then 'Match' else 'Not Match' end
from @T1 t
left join @T2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
```

Comment: It's an _expression_ not a _statement_.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case condition into the select statement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
select t1.id, 
    case t2.source when 0 then 'Not Matched'
        when 1 then 'Match'
        else ''
    end as [status]
from @T1 t1
    inner join @T2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **[`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** expression should be in the **[`SELECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** statement instead of the **[`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** clause, where you can check the value of `source` column and return `Match/No Match` according to that value as:

```
SELECT T2.id,
       CASE T2.source WHEN '1' THEN 'Match' ELSE 'No Match' END Status
FROM @T1 T1 JOIN @T2 T2
ON T1.id = T2.id;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+----------+
| id |  Status  |
+----+----------+
|  1 | No Match |
|  2 | Match    |
|  3 | No Match |
|  4 | Match    |
|  5 | Match    |
+----+----------+
```

You can check it on [the live demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=031bfd11faa043a2202dc4620389f136).

---

This if the `Source` column contains two possible values which is `'0'` or `'1'`, if it may contains other values then:

```
SELECT T2.id,
       CASE T2.source WHEN '1' THEN 'Match'
                      WHEN '0' THEN 'No Match' 
                      WHEN 'Other Value' THEN 'Other Result' -- and so on
       END Status
FROM @T1 T1 JOIN @T2 T2
ON T1.id = T2.id;
```

Finally, storing numbers as strings is a bad idea, consider to use **[`INT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** or **[`BIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** datatype if you need to store just `True/False`